# How to convert .byt to .txt in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to convert .byt file to .txt, I believe it can only be done in matlab. I used this code, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
img = fopen('myfile.byt','r');
save('myfile.txt','img');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fid = fopen('myfile.byt','r');
data = fread(fid,inf,'single');
fclose(fid);

% Manipulate your data, then...

fid = fopen('myfile_new.byt','w');
fwrite(fid,data(:),'single');
fclose(fid);
```

I should see how your data looks like if you want me to figure out how to save it in `txt` format.

Comment: https://github.com/hankmorgan/UnderworldExporter/blob/master/UnityScripts/scripts/Loaders/BytLoader.cs, it looks like a binary image format, so actually this is copied from what everybody does for reading binary data. So you're invited to show me how to read a binary file in Matlab without reinventing the wheel please.

Comment: I cite what? fread? Come on dude, take a breath and relax a bit. I find it funny to see you following me up in every answer I post with accusations of plagiarism. You posted HUNDREDS of lines of codes without referencing every single function you used or every single "common practice" you used. I appreciate your efforts here to make things clean, but this is becoming ridiculous. If you need to read a floating binary file, this is the way to go, plagiarism or now. Period.

Comment: There is NO other way. It's not about picking things from a post or a blog or whatever else. You have a floating point 32 matrix into a binary file? You use fread 'single' and fwrite 'single'. Period. I could have written it by myself too and I would have produced exactly the same 6 lines of code. It's a narrow path and you can't circumvent it. Unless you want to go with Java underlying for the sake of "providing original answers".

Comment: Well dude, I know that a big part of your life consists of searching answers on google and then coming back here to make your moderation things. But if you actually read carefully, what question is not even talking about the same file format :)

Comment: And you should also know that binary images are normally built from a stream of bytes without a neat matrix shape.

Comment: Ok, it seems like nothing can stop you from pursuing your holy mission. But it's not even a duplicate question: if the format was holding different specifications, this question would not just be about "how to read a binary file". Actually the plagiarism way was not 100% clean so let's point out that it's a dulicate question and I shouldn't answer it. Fine man. Fine.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I'm new to matlab, never used it before, only for this one thing, I managed to complete the task.